# iOS App crashes on exit, how to debug?

Tags: ios, debugging, crash, quit

My app crashes when I quit it(not press home button and go to background), I guess the problem is that some objects released in viewDidUnload, are released again in dealloc, but I'm not sure. As my code has more than 10000 lines, is there any tool or method so I can quickly pinpoint the bug? Or is it caused by something else rather than one object being released twice?

Thanks!

Here is a screenshot of left pane:

[image: When crashes]

Also, I tried to log messages in viewDidUnload and dealloc, but did not see any error message.

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    print "viewDidUnload 1";
    // actual method body
    print "viewDidUnload 2";
}
```

the same for dealloc.

Edit 2:
My app uses Core Data, so is there anything I need to manually finalize on exit for Core Data(or it will crash)?

Comment: A debug termination log would be helpful.

Comment: Please post the console output of the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test it on a real device - if the app crashes, a crash log will be generated. It will be available in the Organizer Window of XCode in *Device Logs* section corresponding to your device.

That log will give you the call stack of the crash, probably narrowing the places you need to search.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say if you have not posted any code.

Do you have any crash logs?

How are you releasing in `viewDidUnload`?

```
[_mayVar release];               // 1. on its own this will most likely cause a crash

[_mayVar release]; _myVar = nil; // 2. This is better as sets the pointer to nil

self.myVar = nil;                // 3. If you use properties this is easier than line 2
```

Comment: Thanks, I've uploaded a screenshot.

Comment: Do you think if I test it on real device instead of simulator, I'll see more detailed results?

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem and running it on a real device showed that it crashes in FlurryAnalytics. Do you use that?
I had to remove it completely from the project (not only not starting the session!) to fix this crash.